# Angular JS, how to pass URL parameters to $resouce in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a simple controller where it passes unique integers into my url, but Im running to many issues. I need to change this "4401" dynamically from my controller.

the url Im trying to reach:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=4401/json

```
app.factory('classic',function ($resource) {

    return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=:id/json', {
        get: {
            method: 'JSONP',
            id: '@id'
        }
    });

});
```

and here is my controller

```
app.controller('TestCrtl', function ($scope, classic) {
    init();
    function init(id) {
        $scope.movies = classic.get(id);
    }
    $scope.classicMovies = function(){
        var id = "4403";
        init(id);
    }


    $scope.anctionMovies = function(){
        var id = "4404";
        init(id);
    }
});
```

The error Im getting
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

any help would be highly appreciated.

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" data-ng-click="actionMovies()" class="btn btn-default">Action</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Scary</button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the correct way to implement parameters when using a resource factory:

```
app.factory('movieService',function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=:id/json', {id: '@id'}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray:true, params: {id: '@id'} }
    });
});
```

This can be simplified to:

```
app.factory('movieService',function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=:id/json', {id: '@id'});
});
```

To call this get method you would need to do the following. Note the parameters that are used in the get method.

```
app.controller('TestCrtl', function ($scope, movieService) {

    $scope.classicMovies = function(){
        movieService.query({id: 4403}, function(result){
            $scope.movies = result;
        });
    }
    $scope.anctionMovies = function(){
        movieService.query({id: 4404}, function(result){
            $scope.movies = result;
        });
    }
});
```

Additionally, it should be noted that the resource method call is going to return a promise. You can either set it from the return value of the get method, like you did above (The status of the promise isn't guaranteed), or you can set it in the callback, which guarantees that the promise is resolved.

Comment: well it doesnt seems like it, when I call both classic and action movies I get the same thing

Comment: What URL is generated for both classic and action movies?

Comment: the id doesnt get passes properly :(

Comment: Sorry! Wasn't thinking about both sides of the problem. Take a look at my edit. That should resolve it for you.

Comment: do I have to do anything to update the view/scope, it is always returning the same thing, I really appreciate your help though

Comment: now action movies doesnt get called, for both returns https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=4403/json

Comment: I've simplified the logic some, and renamed the service in my most recent edit. Lets see if that helps. Also - what does the code look like that calls these methods?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75564/discussion-between-adam-o-and-user1429595).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
app.factory('classic',function ($resource) {

    return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=:id/json', {
        get: {
            method: 'JSONP',
            id: '@id'
        }
    });

});
```

And in controller change to :

```
$scope.movies = classic.get(id);
```

Comment: it didnt do it, it calls https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=/json